# Magento 2 in import products attributes sku errors?

Tags: magento2.2, import, csv, magento-2.1.9

```
    We can't find required columns: sku.
```

Column names: "sku product_name    swt_package_quantity    swt_diameter    swt_package_weight  swt_length  swt_width   swt_material    swt_for_use_with    swt_size    swt_product_type    swt_grade_type  swt_number_of_pieces    swt_application swt_package_type swt_body_length    swt_nozzle_size swt_control_type    swt_spray_type  swt_cup_capacity    swt_jar_capacity    swt_hose_length swt_includes    swt_operating_air_press_rat swt_free_type   swt_standard_nozzle swt_tank_capacity   swt_air_intel_size swt_air_hose_inside_diameter swt_average_air_consumption swt_weight  swt_work_air_pressure_psi   swt_work_air_pressure_bar   swt_compressor_rating   swt_pressure_rating swt_air_consumption swt_connection_size swt_thread_type swt_capacity swt_voltage_rating swt_horsepower_rating   swt_number_of_phases    swt_power_rating    swt_displacement    swt_fad swt_speed_rating    swt_cylinder_formation  swt_chisel_shank_size   swt_bore_inside_diameter    swt_piston_stroke_length swt_blows_per_minute   swt_overall_length  swt_phase   swt_displacement_cfm    swt_square_drive_size   swt_bolt_size_capacity  swt_free_speed  swt_maximum_torque_rating   swt_disc_diameter   swt_spindle_thread_size swt_no_load_speed swt_spindle_thread_type   swt_cartridge_size  swt_set_contents    swt_traction_power  swt_stroke_length   swt_sandpaper_size  swt_overall_size    swt_hex_shank_size  swt_bit_capacity    swt_buffer_diameter swt_crown_size  swt_height  swt_overall_height swt_color    swt_container_type  swt_dry_time    swt_blade_width swt_thread_gender   swt_hose_size   swt_finish  swt_maximum_speed_rating    swt_arbor_size  swt_segment_size    swt_material_application    swt_package_color   swt_dimensions  swt_type swt_head_type  swt_shank_type  swt_drive_size  swt_included_angle  swt_head_diameter   swt_shank_diameter  swt_packing swt_wheel_diameter  swt_spare_wheels_yes_no swt_minimum_height  swt_maximum_height  swt_gender  swt_resistant_properties swt_ac_current_measure_range   swt_dc_voltage_measure_range    swt_ac_voltage_measure_range    swt_resistance_measure_range    swt_frequency_measure_range swt_capacitance_measur_range    swt_jaw_size    swt_dc_current_measure_range swt_diode_capacity swt_operating_temp_range    swt_wire_stripper_range swt_standards_met   swt_socket_type swt_plating_material    swt_ring_offset swt_contents    swt_jaw_offset  swt_terminal_type   swt_number_of_teeths    swt_lubricant_type swt_dial_material    swt_noise_level_type    swt_cuff_type   swt_size_range  swt_number_of_filters   swt_organs_covered  swt_sensor_type swt_moisture_free_yes_no    swt_handle_type swt_design  swt_number_of_jaw_positions swt_jaw_opening_size swt_maximum_pressure_rating    swt_roll_length swt_handle_material swt_chain_length    swt_functions   swt_special_features    swt_attachment_type swt_features    swt_lens_material   swt_frame_type  swt_lens_color  swt_lens_type   swt_frame_material swt_disposable_yes_no    swt_battery_size    swt_battery_voltage swt_battery_type    swt_self_life   swt_volume  swt_battery_capacity    swt_charging_time   swt_unit_size   swt_operating_voltage_range swt_base_shape  swt_thickness   swt_storage_instruction swt_adhesive_type   swt_threads_per_inch    swt_blade_angle swt_current_rating  swt_number_of_ways  swt_breaking_capacity   swt_number_of_outlets   swt_entry_type  swt_number_of_poles swt_mounting_type   swt_fitting_type    swt_input_voltage_rating swt_base_type  swt_protection_features swt_cord_length swt_number_of_levers    swt_time_format swt_number_of_cores swt_shape   swt_point_angle swt_bolt_size   swt_maximum_fixing_size swt_drill_size  swt_hole_depth  swt_suitable_application swt_rivet_diameter swt_rivet_length    swt_grip_range  swt_body_material   swt_mandrel_material    swt_mandrel_finish  swt_screw_size  swt_body_finish swt_rivet_tool_type swt_rivet_size  swt_rivet_material  swt_net_weight  swt_pack_size swt_directions_for_use    swt_removes swt_point_type  swt_shank_size  swt_flat_bit_size   swt_working_length  swt_number_of_morse_taper   swt_grit_size   swt_hole_size   swt_sander_size swt_case_material   swt_sewing_material swt_number_of_pockets swt_strap_material    swt_buckle_size swt_adjustable_yes_no   swt_shaft_shape swt_end_type    swt_pattern_type    swt_drive_type  swt_socket_material swt_bit_material    swt_description swt_pipe_size   swt_torque_range    swt_accuracy    swt_box_material swt_ratchet_arch_angle swt_number_of_compartments  swt_load_rating swt_circlip_size    swt_bend_angle  swt_hardness    swt_jaw_type    swt_kit_contents    swt_offset_angle    swt_adhesion_material   swt_applied_method  swt_fuel_type   swt_starting_system swt_frequency_rating    swt_rated_output    swt_maximum_output_rating   swt_fuel_tank_capacity  swt_digital_4_sta_met_yes_no    swt_tank_protector_yes_no   swt_advanced_avr_yes_no swt_14_ah_battery_inc_yes_no    swt_cutting_capacity    swt_cutting_length swt_chuck_mount_type swt_morse_tapper    swt_number_of_jaws  swt_measuring_range swt_graduated_angle swt_range   swt_delivery    swt_drum_capacity   swt_working_pressure    swt_maximum_air_pressure    swt_maximum_outlet_pressure swt_air_inlet_connection    swt_pump_outlet_connection  swt_grease_output   swt_noise_level swt_spare_nozzle_available  swt_supply_form swt_operating_mechanism swt_tip_style   swt_spanner_type    swt_tap_size    swt_jaw_width   swt_body_orintention swt_discharge_current  swt_output_voltage_rating   swt_warranty    swt_threades_per_inch   swt_number_of_rows  swt_pulling_capacity    swt_gross_weight    swt_viewing_area    swt_number_of_sensors   swt_adjustment_type swt_reaction_time swt_maximum_cutting_depth swt_magnification   swt_field_of_view   swt_minimum_focus   swt_objective_aperture_size swt_stadia_line_ratio   swt_horizontal_circle   swt_thread_size swt_handle_finish   swt_shaft_finish    swt_jaw_shape swt_metal_cutting_capacity    swt_stain_steel_cut_capacity    swt_suitable_material   swt_blade_type  swt_tip_material    swt_bit_type    swt_bottom_shape    swt_blade_diameter  swt_input_power_rating  swt_depth_of_cut_90_deg swt_depth_of_cut_45_deg swt_blade_length    swt_minimum_cutting_radius  swt_orbital_mode    swt_annular_cutter_size swt_twist_drill_diameter    swt_magnet_dimension    swt_magnetic_force  swt_spindle_size    swt_drill_chuck_size    swt_number_of_action_modes swt_battery_indicator_type   swt_drill_bit_capacity  swt_core_bit_capacity   swt_bit_shank_type  swt_full_load_impact_rate   swt_housing_material    swt_maximum_lock_torque swt_chuck_type  swt_adjustable_clutch_type  swt_motor_power_rating swt_load_speed   swt_pin_type    swt_coolant_type    swt_drill_type  swt_cutting_machine_type    swt_disc_type   swt_bore_length swt_drill_length    swt_shank_length    swt_cutting_depth   swt_surface_shape   swt_cooling_material    swt_suitable_drill_material swt_insulation_type swt_brush_material  swt_brush_type  swt_shank_bit_size  swt_impact_energy   swt_cutter_length   swt_cap_chuck_size  swt_speed_control_type  swt_handle_grip_speed   swt_handle_design   swt_depth_of_cutting    swt_rabbeting_depth swt_cutting_width   swt_air_volume_range    swt_wind_temperature_range  swt_belt_size   swt_output_power    swt_package_dimensions  swt_sanding_pad_shape   swt_corded_cordless swt_operating_time  swt_number_of_leds  swt_light_adjustment_angle swt_light_movement_type  swt_power_source    swt_fan_adjustment_angle    swt_fan_stand_type  swt_drum_material   swt_gear_material   swt_trigger_switch_size swt_tightening_torque   swt_torque_rating   swt_driver_voltage_rating   swt_bit_shank_size swt_bit_shank_shape  swt_bolt_capacity   swt_noise_reduction_level   swt_motor_type  swt_enclosure_type  swt_switch_type swt_tightening_loosen_torq  swt_indicator_inc_yes_no    swt_bit_shape   swt_hand_operation  swt_lifting_height  swt_pitch swt_number_of_teeth   swt_number_of_points    swt_rod_diameter    swt_terminal_size   swt_wire_stripping_capacity swt_ignition_terminal_size  swt_bit_size    swt_bit_style   swt_working_angle   swt_cutting_angle   swt_number_of_vials swt_display_type swt_system_of_measurement  swt_handle_length   swt_head_mass   swt_blade_thickness swt_crimping_capacity   swt_tool_nest_size  swt_product_use swt_fixings_included_yes_no swt_installation_type   swt_cut_out_type    swt_package_size    swt_backset_size swt_key_type   swt_shackle_diameter    swt_shackle_length  swt_shackle_material    swt_number_of_dials swt_number_of_keys  swt_depth   swt_clearance   swt_external_diameter   swt_external_length swt_lashing_capacity    swt_odor_odorless   swt_end_1_size swt_end_2_size   swt_operating_cmp_air_press swt_cable_length    swt_cable_diameter  swt_conductor_size  swt_connection_type swt_compatible_fittings swt_operator_type   swt_tip_size    swt_material_thickness  swt_oxygen_pressure_rating swt_acetylene_pressure   swt_nozzle_length   swt_inlet_pressure_rating   swt_outlet_pressure swt_inlet_diameter  swt_outlet_diameter swt_flow_capacity   swt_outlet_size swt_compatible_gas_type swt_cutting_thickness   swt_cutting_speed   swt_orifice_size swt_grip_type  swt_insulation_material swt_wire_diameter   swt_series  swt_material_grade  swt_welding_current_range   swt_brazing_rod_type    swt_silver_content  swt_duty_cycle  swt_minimum_electrode_size  swt_maximum_electrode_size swt_protection_class swt_input_current_rating    swt_maximum_flow_rating swt_weighting_capacity  swt_outer_dimensions    swt_inner_dimension swt_no_load_voltage swt_output_current_range    swt_electrode_size  swt_no_load_consumption swt_efficiency  swt_welding_thickness   swt_arc_initiation_method   swt_decline_time    swt_wire_feed_speed swt_power_capacity  swt_suitable_welding_wire   swt_coil_diameter   swt_wire_feeder_type    swt_output_adjust_current   swt_input_power_capacity swt_vernier_reading    swt_measuring_surface_type  swt_face_type   swt_resolution  swt_base_size   swt_frame_finish    swt_angle   swt_thread_form swt_increment   swt_throat_depth    swt_throat_resolution   swt_number_of_blades    swt_threads_per_mm swt_screw_pitch  swt_plating_type    swt_graduation  swt_dial_diameter   swt_plunger_material    swt_extension_rod   swt_lower_column_length swt_upper_column_length swt_maximum_lifting_height  swt_minimum_lifting_height  swt_screw_extension_size swt_increment_height   swt_saddle_size swt_maximum_pulling_capacity    swt_working_load    swt_gear_ratio  swt_nominal_breaking_load   swt_front_overall_width swt_back_overall_width  swt_base_length swt_base_width_front    swt_base_width_rear swt_maximum_working_space   swt_minimum_working_space   swt_work_bed_width  swt_number_of_strokes   swt_coating_type    swt_extension_length    swt_clamping_type   swt_quantity    swt_lamp_type   swt_burn_time   swt_folded_size swt_extended_open_size  swt_ratchet_length  swt_breaking_strength   swt_working_time    swt_water_proof_yes_no  swt_lumens  swt_light_type  swt_number_of_batteries swt_lining_material swt_stand_material  swt_adjustable_length swt_compatible_material   swt_initial_cure_time   swt_final_cure_time swt_full_strength_time  swt_minimum_material_depth  swt_fixing_size swt_point_size  swt_slip_yes_no swt_handle_color    swt_blade_material  swt_bade_material swt_maximum_adjustable_size   swt_socket_size swt_measuring_distance  swt_notch_size  swt_energy_saving   swt_dimmable_yes_no swt_lamp_life   swt_clamping_capacity   swt_spread_size swt_jaw_adjustment_range    swt_coating_material swt_work_air_pressure  swt_frame_proof_load_rating swt_clamp_capacity  swt_bar_length  swt_rod_material    swt_pipe_cutting_capacity   swt_sweatband_color swt_shell_color swt_lining_color    swt_working_width   swt_holding_capacity    swt_rated_life swt_number_of_ply    swt_hose_connector_size swt_sprayer_material    swt_stem_material   swt_spray_pattern   swt_maximum_inside_diameter swt_minimum_inside_diameter swt_maximum_wall_thickness  swt_minimum_wall_thickness swt_maximum_cutting_capacity swt_buffer_material swt_coverage_range  swt_water_pressure_rating   swt_stream_length   swt_spray_range swt_maximum_diameter    swt_running_time    swt_packaging   swt_spindle_speed   swt_die_size    swt_die_heads swt_chain_size    swt_actual_od_capacity  swt_screw_diameter  swt_tube_size   swt_bend_radius swt_thread_per_inch swt_rod_size    swt_thread_pitch    swt_die_head_size   swt_thread_direction    swt_insulated_yes_no    swt_shade swt_maximum_measuring_force   swt_scale_range swt_measuring_type  swt_number_of_wipes swt_towel_size  swt_flavour swt_self_adhesive_sign  swt_legend_style    swt_fragrance   swt_bristle_material    swt_style   swt_hone_type   swt_gear_type swt_self_centering_type   swt_chuck_size  swt_shaft_material  swt_cutter_material swt_working_action  swt_long_nose_size  swt_side_cutter_size    swt_wattage swt_air_flow_rate   swt_hole_saw_diameter   swt_screw_thread_shank_size swt_hex_size swt_inside_size    swt_tip_color   swt_hndle_color swt_shank_shape swt_spanner_size    swt_fitting_size    swt_outside_diameter    swt_outside_square_size swt_recommend_drill_size    swt_nut_size    swt_factory_standard_number swt_piston_ring_diameter swt_blade_size swt_lifting_capacity    swt_grit_grade  swt_maximum_nut_size    swt_throat_width    swt_puller_reach_size   swt_number_of_puller_comb   swt_reach_size  swt_maximum_exte_spread_size    swt_external_spread_size    swt_inside_diameter swt_ram_extension   swt_external_reach  swt_maximum_reach_distance  swt_gauge_diameter  swt_probe_size  swt_cup_diameter    swt_velocity_ratio  swt_multiplication_factor   swt_face_size   swt_head_material   swt_minimum_depth   swt_engine_rating swt_welder_voltage    swt_alternator_volt_rating  swt_starting_type   swt_engine_capacity swt_welder_capacity swt_alternator_head_size    swt_zip_material    swt_latex_free_yes_no   swt_cuff_size   swt_resistance_properties   swt_leather_thickness swt_closure_type  swt_mesh_size   swt_md_strength swt_td_strength swt_melting_point   swt_upper_material  swt_sole_material   swt_insock_material swt_steel_toe_cap   swt_toe_cap_type    swt_mid_outsole_type    swt_safety_toe_cap swt_anti_penetra_sole_yes_no swt_inner_sole_material swt_outsole_material    swt_midsole_material    swt_tip_end_style   swt_elecricans_drive_size   swt_mechanics_drive_size    swt_phillips_drive_size swt_stubby_size swt_working_voltage swt_maximum_safe_speed  swt_wire_size   swt_bore_diameter" are invalid

```
How to solve this issues?
```

Comment: woow you just copy/paste the whole error :). One thing is that probably you didn't add those custom attributes. You can either add them manually or add them via additional attribute column in csv. Export one sample csv from your shop and then compare it with your own csv.

Comment: thank you so much ! its working but small issues... is there drop down  values count only accept limited storage more then values not added in drop down box.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
    using the csv file formats in limit of values will be imported, and also remove the empty columns and rows.


After php bin/magento setup:di:compile

php bin/magento indexer:reindex
php bin/magento cache:clean

and give me a permissions..
```